# Session data doesn't persist - php configuration issue?

Tags: php, html, session, post

I have the following code snippet in my file:-

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fromPanel'] = "abcd";

<form method="post" action="/m/xyz.php">
    <div class="text inputcaption"><b><?= _("Email")?></b></div>
    <input type="email" name="username" value="<?=$objMobile->GetEmail()?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

When the file `xyz.php` is called on post request, the `$_SESSION` array is coming empty. Please note `session_start();` was given in `xyz.php` before printing the session array. Why is the session array getting empty by itself.

Code for xyz.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    print "<post>";
?>
```

Please find the session settings obtained through phpinfo();

```
|---------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| Session Support                 | enabled             |                     |
| Registered                      | save handlers       | files user          |
| Registered                      | serializer handlers | php php_binary wddx |
|                                 |                     |                     |
|---------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| Directive                       | Local Value         | Master Value        |
|---------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| session.auto_start              | Off                 | Off                 |
| session.bug_compat_42           | On                  | On                  |
| session.bug_compat_warn         | On                  | On                  |
| session.cache_expire            | 180                 | 180                 |
| session.cache_limiter           | nocache             | nocache             |
| session.cookie_domain           | no value            | no value            |
| session.cookie_httponly         | Off                 | Off                 |
| session.cookie_lifetime         | 0                   | 0                   |
| session.cookie_path             | /                   | /                   |
| session.cookie_secure           | Off                 | Off                 |
| session.entropy_file            | no value            | no value            |
| session.entropy_length          | 0                   | 0                   |
| session.gc_divisor              | 100                 | 100                 |
| session.gc_maxlifetime          | 1440                | 1440                |
| session.gc_probability          | 1                   | 1                   |
| session.hash_bits_per_character | 4                   | 4                   |
| session.hash_function           | 0                   | 0                   |
| session.name                    | PHPSESSID           | PHPSESSID           |
| session.referer_check           | no value            | no value            |
| session.save_handler            | files               | files               |
| session.save_path               | C:\Windows\Temp     | C:\Windows\Temp     |
| session.serialize_handler       | php                 | php                 |
| session.use_cookies             | On                  | On                  |
| session.use_only_cookies        | Off                 | Off                 |
| session.use_trans_sid           | 0                   | 0                   |
|---------------------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
```

On enabling error_reporting, following warnings were seen:

```
Warning:  Unknown: open(C:\Windows\Temp\sess_1037ca26d3ebb62017eddc9cbfb107e2, O_RDWR) failed: Invalid argument (22) in Unknown on line 0

Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\Windows\Temp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Silly question, but do you have the same `session_start();` in your xyz.php file right at the top?

Comment: Please show us the code from the file `xyz.php` where you output the `$_SESSION` array and where you start the session!

Comment: Ofcourse i have put session_start(); at the top in xyz.php, but still, this occurs, I am thinking something related to server configurations or php.ini configurations could be an issue.

Comment: Please find the code for xyz.php in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I converted your snippet to working code and it runs like a charm.
Please provide a complete non-working example so we can help you.

a.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['fromPanel'] = "abcd";
?>

<form method="post" action="./b.php">
    <input type="email" name="username" value="john@example.com">
</form>
```

b.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

var_dump( $_SESSION['fromPanel'] );
var_dump( $_POST['username'] );

echo '<a href="./_test.php">back to form</a>';
```

result output after sending the form (with enter in input):

```
string 'abcd' (length=4)

string 'john@example.com' (length=16)

back to form
```

N.B: Use `<label for="id-of-form">caption</label>` instead of `<div class="text inputcaption"></div>`

Comment: Ofcourse it works for some systems and thus it seems like a configuration issue. But, what configurations to be changed is the question.

Comment: So you should have written exactly that in your question in the first place. ;) It was a first start as you did not provide much information.

Answer (score 0):

More things to check:

1. Does the browser you are using accept cookies?
2. Clear cache and cookies, call `session_regenerate_id()` after `session_start()` to make sure it's not some old testing stuff that gives you trouble.
3. Is the session.save_path set and writeable? Check your `phpinfo();` output.
4. Is xyz.php on the same domain? Cookies not allowed crosss domain.
5. Post your session.xyz settings.
6. Is this your own server? Try it on a hosted webspace or vice versa.
7. make sure there is no whitespace before the session_start() call.
8. call `error_reporting(E_ALL)` first thing.
9. make your example publicly available so others can check, too.
10. Go and have a beer. It will work next week. ;)

Comment: session settings included with the issue and warning encountered also enclosed.

Comment: Here we are. The the warnings state that the webserver cannot persist the session data. Reason is probably that you need to escape the backslash. Try setting `session.save_path`to `C:\\Windows\\Temp` in your php.ini. Alternatively replace the backslashes with (single) forward slashes.

Answer (score -2):

If you are including a common file in all the views like header.php or common.php just write session_start() at the top.

Comment: you are assuming that there would some file inclided??